# Cannot ping Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ping, icmp

I just created a server using AWS Free tier. I have created a new Windows instance in Ireland. I just trying to pin the public IP but it doesn't response. I see that there are an "inbound" rules section, could you provide more info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to ping an EC2 instance you will need to enable ICMP requests.

1. Open the EC2 Console.
2. Click on “**Security Groups**”. Choose the required security group.
3. Click on the “**Inbound**” tab.
4. Add a new EC2 security group inbound rule:

   **Type**: Custom ICMP rule - IPv4

   **Protocol**: Echo request

   **Source**: Anywhere (This will make your instance reply the requests from anywhere)

Also, I'd suggest reading the [Amazon EC2 Security Group Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) to understand how it works and how it can help you to protect your applications and data.